# Android EditText can't handle large file

Tags: android, android-edittext

I notice that if most of the text inside EditText View is colorize with different colour (E.g. ForegroundColorSpan ), the EditText becomes very slow when the number of line is large. (>500 lines)

I am trying to use EditText for typing code and do syntax highlighting using Spannable object.

Anyone has any solution to this problem? Do i have to write my own EditText view? If that is the case then how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

never had this problem , but have you tried to temporary disable the color when editing , and return the color after editing?
also , would it be possible to use listview of editTexts ?